# How to get saved id in SugarORM?

Tags: android, sqlite, sugarorm

[SugarORM](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/index.html), in my opinion, is the easiest SQLite library to use and proven to be extremely helpful for junior Android developer like me. SugarORM automatically creates the table and add an AUTO_INCREMENT id column for every java class extending SugarRecord.

Inserting a new row can be as easy as `someJavaObject.save()`. But how can I get the inserted id once that row is inserted? In PHP I can do something like `$id = mysql_insert_id();` after insertion.

I understand that I can just get the id of last row in the table. But the insertion of new row can somehow be very unpredictable. Let's say I have an activity and a service inserting a new row at the same time, I want to avoid getting the wrong id.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: doesn't `save()` return it? Like `long id = someJavaObject.save()`

Comment: I'll go ahead and try that, will be back in a minute

Comment: @Stan it seems that I've been importing SugarORM wrongly. SugarRecord.class does return long, but the generated code is void. THANK YOU! put it as an answer and I'll accept it right away.

Comment: You may explain further how you imported sugarORM. We may help you with this as well

Comment: @blender turns out I'm importing it right, however the save() points to generated java code located in build folder, the problem seems to resolve after gradle cleaning. Thanks

Comment: @Anggrian Can you specify what you mean with "after gradle cleaning"? I tried the "clean project" and "build project" options but I'm not familiar with the term "gradle cleaning". I only get `public void save()`, not `public long save()`.

Comment: @Harti sorry I just read this post again. As a substitute, you could always use "long id = object.getId()" after "object.save()".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `save()` method has to return it. Like:

```
 long id = someJavaObject.save()
```

Answer (score 3):

or try:

```
someJavaObject.save()
long id = someJavaObject.getId();
```

Answer (score 1):

As Stan mentioned, save actually returns the id as long value. I used this by today.
If you want to use this for a freshly created row you may do something like this:
Region reg2 = new Region("Graz", 20, 20);
reg1.setId(reg1.save());